# Daily reputation is not counted correctly on profile page

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, achievements-dialog, daily-reputation-badges

As we all know, we can achieve an Epic and Legendary badges when we hit the daily reputation cap of 200 points per day for 50/150 times.

The question is - which points count here? Just the upvotes for our questions (+5) / answers (+10)? Or accepted answers (+15) as well?

Just a few minutes ago I got 200 points in total (counting accepted answers) and my  badge progress was increased from 56 to 57:

[image]

The thing is, when I click the badge details in my profile details, I can see that I scored today just 140/200 points (so only +5 and +10 were counted):

[image]

Is it a bug in UI or counting mechanism?